# Making a multi page web app using react JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, react-router

Me and my team are trying to make a multi-page react app and each of us had been given one-one page to work on, for simplicity let us assume we have only 3 pages- I had to design login/sign-up, the other had to design the home page where the display information would be dynamically fetched from the API (let's call it the API page for simplicity).
I have made the login and sign up pages by keeping the HTML file as it is, and I have used react just to render the forms and perform form validation and account validation by hitting API in the backend in react, and I still need to call the /login.html page; whereas my friend has converted the whole HTML file into a react component, and he just renders the different components like sidebar, searchbar etc into one js file to display the webpage.

Which of the above is a better method to make a react webpage? 
P.S- All the 3 pages are working absolutely fine independently.

How do we integrate all the 3 pages and also ensure that one is not able to access the API page unless and until he/she has logged in?

We are using webpack config to run our files.

Comment: I suggest you and your 'team' use --> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: Thanks! Really worked